# Why do my triggers end up with a blank control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF I'm trying to create a "flag" control that displays a checkmark or an X based on a bound dependency property (`Flag`)

```
<UserControl x:Name="Root" (Other user control stuff)>
     <ContentControl Height="20" x:Name="flagHolder">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Flag}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource XIcon}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Flag}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{StaticResource CheckIcon}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="ForestGreen"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>     
</UserControl>
```

On startup every icon is correct (I have several of these controls, each bound to different values). However, when I toggle a few (one that was "off" turns "on" and the one currently "on" turns "off") I see two things:

1. The control that was turned "on" has become a green check (as desired)
2. The control that was turned "off" is now just blank

Inspecting the visual tree seems to indicate that everything is working (though I could easily be missing something here), and the order of the triggers doesn't seem to matter. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example icon, the path geometry is removed since its just noise:

```
<Viewbox x:Key="CheckIcon" x:Shared="False">
    <Path Style="{StaticResource IconPathStyle}">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="Bunch of SVG" FillRule="NonZero"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Why not template a checkbox instead?

Comment: @LeiYang I could, but its not really a checkbox (no user input here, just status). A checkbox wouldn't work if I had more than two states also. I was able to get around it another way, but it seems like this code should work and I would like to understand why its broken/the best way to fix it.

Comment: Then you are creating custom controls, seems better use code behind instead of xaml? (seems your points are very high, so I believe your problem may be interesting.^_^)

Comment: @LeiYang Also a valid solution that I considered using (only reason I didn't is all the extra typing for resources/brush creation is super annoying). Code-behind also doesn't work so well if this was in a data template or similar (though oddly enough, a similar solution I have in a `DataTemplate` *does* work). Converting this to use the `ContentTemplate` property and a `DataTemplate` doesn't seem to fix the problem here though.

Comment: Could you please complete your _XAML_ code, i.e. include `Root` control and `XIcon` and `CheckIcon` resources?

Comment: @Grx70 "Root" is just the user control above it, but sure. `XIcon` and `CheckIcon` are just Viewboxes with a Path inside them; not sure why that would help; they work (and display properly) on initial load, if you want me to try a simpler control; I can.

Comment: Have you tried to set the deactivated style as normal style (not as datatrigger) and just leave in the trigger where it changes to True? I think when the trigger is reset, it goes back to the default look as the False one is not taken into consideration.

Comment: @Scoregraphic Haven't tried that will do so in the morning. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Can you additionally post the ViewBoxes with their paths? I've made an perfectly working example here in 3 minutes and cannot reproduce your issue so i guess it's either the ViewBox or the Path

Comment: Do the `Viewbox`es have `x:Shared="False"` set? It sounds like the problem could be that you're using one instance of `Viewbox` in several places, which is not allowed - any element can only have one visual tree parent (a `ContentControl` in your case). If that's not it, you should be able to produce at least two `X` or two `Check` icons simultaneously - can you try that?

Comment: @Grx70 Yes, x:Shared is set to false. I have multiple instances of these controls all over the place (ran into that one a while back). Thanks for asking though. I'll post an example when I try Scoregraphic's suggestion.

Comment: I guess it would be beneficial if you tried to diagnose why exactly the control is blank. Possible causes are a) `ContentControl.Content` is not set; b) height or width of `ContentControl`, `Viewbox` or `Path` is 0; c) `Visibility` of any of those is `Hidden` or `Collapsed` d) `ContentControl.Foreground` or `Path.Fill` is null or transparent; e) there's a glitch in the framework which prevents the path from being drawn properly. In the latter case you could try resizing the control and see if the icon shows.

Comment: @lokusking Sample icon XAML added; the geometry itself is obviously fine since it draws correctly on load

Comment: @lokusking Seems to be a timing issue of some sort. If I set some breakpoints through the process everything works. Though not *always*. Some delay (thread.sleep, timer) does not guarantee it.

Comment: @Grx70 All of those seem to be fine except nothing draws; even if I resize the window (granted, not the control directly)

Comment: @Scoregraphic Your suggestion had no effect :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue, but here what I have and it's working:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <Viewbox  x:Key="CheckIcon" x:Shared="False">
      <Canvas Height="24" Width="32">
        <Path Width="7.85446" Height="8.57578" Canvas.Left="-0.0522281" Canvas.Top="-0.100391" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.04192" StrokeMiterLimit="2.75" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 0.468732,4.66838L 3.03345,7.95443L 7.28127,0.420569"/>
      </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

      <Viewbox  x:Key="XIcon" x:Shared="False">
      <Canvas Height="24" Width="32">
        <Path Data="M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Width="12" Height="12" />
       </Canvas>
      </Viewbox>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**YesNo.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.YesNo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Name="Root">

  <ContentControl Height="20" Name="flagHolder">
    <ContentControl.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ContentControl">

        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Flag}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource XIcon}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Flag}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{StaticResource CheckIcon}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="ForestGreen"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
  </ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```

**YesNo.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class YesNo : UserControl
    {
        public YesNo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FlagProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Flag", typeof(bool), typeof(YesNo), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool Flag {
            get {
                return (bool) GetValue(FlagProperty);
            }
            set {
                SetValue(FlagProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="" Width="400" Height="400">

  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="50">
    <wpfApplication1:YesNo Flag="{Binding Flag1}"/>
    <wpfApplication1:YesNo Flag="{Binding Flag2}"/>
    <wpfApplication1:YesNo Flag="{Binding Flag2}"/>
    <wpfApplication1:YesNo Flag="{Binding Flag1}"/>
    <Button Content="Toggle" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _flag1;
    private bool _flag2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Flag1 = true;
        Flag2 = false;
    }
    public bool Flag1 {
        get {
            return _flag1;
        }
        set {
            _flag1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Flag2 {
        get {
            return _flag2;
        }
        set {
            _flag2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Flag1 = !Flag1;
        Flag2 = !Flag2;
    }
}
```

**How it looks like:**

[image: screenshot]

Video: http://www.screencast.com/t/J5IY7DR3Ry

Comment: Were you able to toggle your flags via a binding? Mine also always appear correctly on startup, its just when I start toggling that it gets weird.

Comment: Well, glad you got it working... This must be some sort of timing issue, as I see it on my end with nearly identical code, and the behavior changes if I'm hitting breakpoitns, etc.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Sadly, I can't share your feelings about the fact I've made it working - I hoped to help you. I doubt it's a timing issue itself, I bet it's some code of yours creating the issue. Make a good repro of your problem, otherwise your question has little sense, everyone will be doomed guessing...

Comment: Might be hard; the whole program involves communicating with multiple FTDI USB-Serial adapters and verifying that comms are coming through. Without the devices and associated harnessing, it would be very difficult for someone else to get my exact setup/timing working (hence the reduced example). Other programs I've done these kinds of data triggers with seem to work fine.

Comment: To be clear; the only code that is different here is the code setting the bound value of the flag

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think we are not interested in devices or having exactly the same setup. It's enough to emulate the work that's happening behind the scenes. For example, if you are switching flags with a high frequency - that might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: It is certainly possible that there is a "flutter" of flag toggles/sets. I can try to emulate that or log out the number of sets I'm getting.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I've set up a timer to try the case with frequent toogles of flag, so in 2 sec it was changed ~650 times, but still worked as expected. There must be something else in your scenario that breaks it...

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that I have a bit of a problem when I am hitting breakpoints during a toggle. The whole thing is super bizzare because even if my property update doesn't get through, I can't figure out why the control would be *blank* instead of just keeping its current state